# executor channel - InheritableThreadLocal issue

Tags: spring-integration

I am using executor channel for parallel calls.

```
<task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="5"/>
<int:channel id="executorChannel">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="taskExecutor"/>
</int:channel>
```

I am using InheritableThreadLocal variable, it is reset to the initial value after 6th call because of the pool-size declared as 5.

In other words, thread local value from 1-10 read as 1-5 and again 1-5.
Other than ThreadLocal variable issue, everything is working fine.

please advise on the fix.

Here is the sample Classes:
1. HeaderContext - to store InheritableThreadLocal variable

```
public final class HeaderContext {

    private HeaderContext() {}

    private static final InheritableThreadLocal<String> GID = new InheritableThreadLocal<String>() {
        @Override
        protected String initialValue() {
            return new String();
        }
    };

    public static void clear() {
        GID.remove();
    }

    public static void setGID(String gid) {
        GID.set(gid);
    }

    public static String getGID() {
        return GID.get();
    }
}
```

2. TestGateway

```
@Component
public interface TestGateway {
        String testMethod(String name);
}
```

3. TestActivator

```
@Component
public class TestActivator {

    public String testMethod(String name){
        System.out.println("GID from Inheritable thread local ->"+HeaderContext.getGID());
        return name;
    }
}
```

4. Test Class

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:exec-channel-si.xml" })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ThreadLocalGatewayTest {

    @Autowired
    TestGateway testGateway;

    @Test
    public void testBrokerageGateway() throws InterruptedException {

        for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
            try {
                HeaderContext.setGID("gid"+i);
                System.out.println("done->" + testGateway.testMethod("name"+i));

            } finally {
                HeaderContext.clear(); 
            }
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
    }

}
```

5. SI context

```
<task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="2"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="sample.test"/>
<int:channel id="executorChannel">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="taskExecutor"/>
</int:channel>

<int:gateway id="testGateway"
    service-interface="sample.test.TestGateway"
    default-request-channel="executorChannel">
</int:gateway>
<int:service-activator input-channel="executorChannel" ref="testActivator"/>
```

**Output**

```
GID from Inheritable thread local ->gid1
output->name1
GID from Inheritable thread local ->gid2
output->name2
GID from Inheritable thread local ->gid1
output->name3
GID from Inheritable thread local ->gid2
output->name4
GID from Inheritable thread local ->gid1
output->name5
```

Comment: Would great if you'd share some code play from our side.

Comment: I have edited the post with simple example..your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm sure when you print `ThreadId` in your service, you won't be surprised that you reuse thread for your purpose:

```
name-> name1 in the inheritable thread local -> gid1 for thread: pool-1-thread-1
name-> name2 in the inheritable thread local -> gid2 for thread: pool-1-thread-2
name-> name3 in the inheritable thread local -> gid3 for thread: pool-1-thread-3
name-> name4 in the inheritable thread local -> gid4 for thread: pool-1-thread-4
name-> name5 in the inheritable thread local -> gid5 for thread: pool-1-thread-5
name-> name6 in the inheritable thread local -> gid4 for thread: pool-1-thread-4
name-> name10 in the inheritable thread local -> gid1 for thread: pool-1-thread-1
name-> name8 in the inheritable thread local -> gid2 for thread: pool-1-thread-2
name-> name9 in the inheritable thread local -> gid3 for thread: pool-1-thread-3
name-> name7 in the inheritable thread local -> gid5 for thread: pool-1-thread-5
```

That is result of the simple test:

```
private static final ThreadLocal<String> threadLocal = new InheritableThreadLocal<>();

@Test
public void testInheritableThreadLocal() throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    final CountDownLatch stopLatch = new CountDownLatch(10);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        final int j = i;
        try {
            threadLocal.set("gid" + i);
            executorService.execute(() -> {
                System.out.println("name-> " + "name " + j + " in the inheritable thread local -> "
                        + threadLocal.get() + " for thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                stopLatch.countDown();
            });
        }
        finally {
            threadLocal.remove();
        }
    }
    assertTrue(stopLatch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
}
```

Now let's take a look into `ThreadLocal` JavaDocs:

```
 * This class provides thread-local variables.  These variables differ from
 * their normal counterparts in that each thread that accesses one (via its
 * {@code get} or {@code set} method) has its own, independently initialized
 * copy of the variable.
```

So, each thread has its own copy of variables and change to them in one thread doesn't affect another thread.

The `InheritableThreadLocal` in the main Thread is as a normal `ThreadLocal`. Only with that gain that a new spawned child `Thread` will get a current copy of the `main` `ThreadLocal`. That's why we see a fresh values for each new thread, but when reuse that child thread, like it is in case of `ThreadPool`, we still see its own old value.

Please, read more RTFM on the matter!

Hope that clear